# Sub-query, group and having in SilverStripe ORM

Tags: orm, group-by, subquery, silverstripe, having

I'm using SilverStripe ORM.

I need to get all companies that are at least in ALL of the desired Specializing (no less):

```
class CompanyPage extends Page {    
    private static $many_many = [
        "Specializings" => "Specializing",
    ];
}

class Specializing extends DataObject {
    private static $belongs_many_many = [
        "CompanyPages" => "CompanyPage",
    ];
}
```

I have an array filled with desiring specializing ids ( $specIds ).
This gets companies that are at at least in one of the desired specializing, but it isn't that I need.

```
$companyPages = CompanyPage::get()->filter([
    "Specializings.ID:ExactMatch" => $specIds,
]);
```

I can achive my task with this SQL-query

```
select * from CompanyPage c1 join (
  select c.ID from CompanyPage c 
  join CompanyPage_Specializings cs on cs.CompanyPageID = c.ID
  where cs.SpecializingID in (14,15)
  group by c.ID having count(c.ID) = 2
) c2 on c1.ID = c2.ID
```

But how can I achive it with SilverStripe ORM?
I can't find anything about having by aggregated functions in ORM

Answer (score 2):

You can use SQLQuery to build more complex DB queries in SilverStripe or if you want to run the RAW SQL you can use DB:Query()

https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/model/sql_query/

Both of these will return a MySQLResultSet rather than a SS_List which means when you iterate over the code you would use something like this

```
foreach($results AS $result){
    $varname = $results['propertyname'];
}
```

rather than the below if you used the straight SS ORM.

```
foreach($results AS $result){
    $varname = $results->propertyname;
}
```

Once you have the MySQLResult set you could iterate through it to build an ArrayList which you can use in your template or alternatively use this Module to convert the MySQLResultSet to a SS_List (just remember if you use this module that the relationship benefit that you get from the straight ORM isn't maintained - e.g. $has_one relationships etc).

https://github.com/burnbright/silverstripe-sqlquerylist

I hope this helps.